# Overlay Image on Tabbed Frame Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing an app for myself that (in this case) displays a list of items. However, this list of items takes about 10 seconds to pull, so in the meantime, I would like to show the user a loading screen. Currently, my program uses the `place` method to place, and then remove a gif (animated using a custom image class), like this:
[image]

and fully loaded:

[image]

However, I have another frame (in the notebook- you can see the tabs) that I will eventually code to have content and an independent loading image (it will start/stop at different times than the first tab). However, when I move to the second tab while the first tab is loading, the place manager unwantedly keeps the image there:

[image]

How can I get this image to only display on the first tab but not the second? Since this is a project for myself, I am not focused on perfection, and if necessary, I will most likely just add a text element to the treeview stating it is loading (the other frame will also have a treeview too). I would also rather not learn a new language (I know some java and JS but python is my strength), because, as I said before, this is just a hobby for me.

Here is a minimal reproducible example. The code needs one file in the same directory (img.png) to run. You will notice that the loading image will be present in both tab1 and tab2, even though tab2 already has data.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from time import sleep
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x300')
root.title('Notebook Demo')

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280)
frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=400, height=280)

frame1.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
frame2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

notebook.add(frame1, text='1')
notebook.add(frame2, text='2')

label1 = ttk.Label(frame1, text = "stuff of 1 - loading")
label2 = tk.Label(frame2, text="label 2 data: already here", width=60, height=15)

label1.pack()
label2.pack()

def load_data():
    label1.config(text='label 1 data: 10110')
    label2.place_forget()

image1 = Image.open("img.png").resize((50,100))
test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)    
label2 = ttk.Label(image=test)
label2.image = test
label2.place(x=30,y=30)
root.after(5000,load_data)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: While your description gives an idea of what you have tried, we can work better with some code to reproduce the issue, known as [mre]. This makes it easier for us to alter your code and dont have to rewrite the problematic code first.

Comment: @anonymous `ttk.Label(image=test)` if no positional argument, means a argument without `=`, is given as the master parameter, the `root` window is set by default. Either you give a master to it (i.e `ttk.Label(frame1,image=test)`) or you go for the optional argument in the geometry manager named *_in* (i.e `label2.place(_in=frame1,x=30,y=30)` to make sure the image is only shown if the master does. BTW: Not sure if `_in=frame1` will work since place is the *careless* geometry manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the problem relays on..:

> `ttk.Label(image=test)` if no positional argument, means a argument
> without `=`, is given as the master parameter, the `root` window is set by
> default.

Give a master to it (i.e `ttk.Label(frame1,image=test)`)